# if condition with or conditions for Session variable check in php

Tags: php, if-statement, session-variables, or-condition

i want to verify my session variables with $_GET['check_string']. it is right ?

```
$check_string=$_GET['check_string'];
if($_SESSION['check_string']==$c_string || isset($_GET['return'])){

}
```

Comment: Where did `$c_string` came from?

Comment: `$c_string`  need to be `$check_string` and `||` need to be `&&`

Comment: I think `$c_string` should be  `$check_string`.

Comment: question is not clear..please correct you question.. $c_strign and other variables are confusing..

Comment: 1) I want to use OR condition..2) sorry for $c_string.. it is $check_string.